# Get Contents of a User-Edited Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am trying to take user-entered data in a content editable `textarea` and POST it, but the user-edited fields always have `textContent` of `""`. In the following code segment the `.entryRow`(`obj`) contains numerous `td` (`cells`) and it is from these cells that I am trying to get the user-entered `textContent`. I have tried using `val()` and that does not seem to work, either.

*Content Gathering Segment*

```
$('.entryRow').each(function (i, obj) {

                    //Creates a JSON object based on each 'td' for current .entryRow(obj)
                    var dataObject = JSON.stringify({
                        'Id': obj.cells[0].textContent,
                        'TeamName': obj.cells[1].textContent,
                    });

                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Edit/SetSortieData',
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        data: dataObject
                    });

                });
```

*Relevant Segment from MVC View*:

In this example, the `@sortie.TeamName` segment is empty and expected to be supplied by the user in-browser.

```
@foreach (var sortie in Model)
    {
        <tr contenteditable="true" class="entryRow">
            <td style="display:none"><textarea id="Id">@sortie.Id</textarea> </td>
            <td><textarea id="TeamName">@sortie.TeamName</textarea></td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try just getting the values from the textareas

```
var dataObject = JSON.stringify({
    'Id': $(obj.cells[0]).find('textarea').val(),
    'TeamName': $(obj.cells[1]).find('textarea').val()
});
```

Comment: This works great! For some reason .val() wasn't working with the syntax I tried first. Thanks!